# How to develop for Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development, development

I read on the Ubuntu site about development, and I'm downloading the Ubuntu SDK currently, but I just had some questions that the site didn't answer for me when I was looking around.

Is the Ubuntu SDK strictly for Ubuntu mobile, or is it for the computer OS, or both?

I'm currently using a Ubuntu Machine, and I also have the tools I need to develop for Ubuntu. 
I would like to know if there is a difference in developing for Ubuntu Touch OS and the Ubuntu OS. Like OSX and iOS both have a core language of Objective-C, but both platforms use two different SDK's since they are two different operating systems.

I also would like to know of any resources to assist me, being that I'm new to these particular tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I know how to program in C/C++, Javascript and PHP and I want to develop some GUI tools for Ubuntu. How shall I start?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319537/i-know-how-to-program-in-c-c-javascript-and-php-and-i-want-to-develop-some-gu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need an ubuntu machine to develop for ubuntu touch

getting started:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/

apidocs:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/overview-ubuntu-sdk.htmlhttp://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-qmltypereference.html

Comment: I'm currently using a Ubuntu Machine, I also have the tools I need to develop for Ubuntu. I would like to know if there is a difference in developing for Ubuntu Touch OS and the Ubuntu OS. Like OSX and iOS both have a core language of Objective-C, but both platforms use two different SDK's since they are two different operating systems. I also would like to know of any resources to assist me, being that I'm new to these particular tools.

Comment: You can develop with qml and qt4 for both.

Comment: @Casey That comment looks like a very well written question which should be in your question. Consider improving your question with it. :)

Comment: @Kupiakos I have qt5, and the Ubuntu SDK, maybe you could post this as answer to my question with some more details, and answer my resources question, if so I think you can accurately answer my question!

Comment: @gertvdijk I think I will! :)