# No headphone sound with Kernel 5.8.1 (custom)

Tags: sound, kernel, headphones

I've compiled a custom kernel 5.8.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.1 using [modprobed-db](https://github.com/graysky2/modprobed-db) and there is no sound coming through my headphone jack. Speakers are fine. Previous custom kernels in the 5.6 series did not have this problem. I suspect it cropped up in the 5.7 series (although I did not test it).

I'm not sure how to proceed to diagnose and solve this problem. My laptop is an ASUS UX430UA and my soundcard (through lspci) is:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```

Can someone offer some advice on how to go about fixing this problem (if it's even possible)? Fooling around with `pavucontrol` and `alsa-mixer` hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Many thanks.

Edit: output of `sudo lshw -C sound` ...

```
  *-usb:0
       description: Video
       product: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
       vendor: 04081-0009800017171014764
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@1:6
       version: 0.01
       serial: 200901010001
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:129 memory:ef128000-ef12bfff memory:ef100000-ef10ffff
```

Comment: Please update Your question with the output of the command `sudo lshw -C sound`.

Answer (score 2):

**The solution to your problem is to use a supported kernel.**  You've already told us that the issue does not exist when using a supported kernel.

Kernel 5.8.1 at the time of your question is the most recent "bleeding edge" kernel on [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/).

This kernel is currently not supported on **any** Ubuntu release, especially 20.04 which is a **long term stable release**.  It has not undergone enough testing and process review to be stable enough for Ubuntu.  Simply put, this kernel is not really finished yet.

By installing the bleeding edge kernel, you are now a tester.

Again this kernel is not yet supported which means it's not expected to work quite right. Maybe you want to get involved with the [development of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335880/how-to-develop-for-ubuntu) or [file a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug/)?

Comment: It is marked as stable (on [kernel.org](https://kernel.org/))

Comment: Here's my alsa-info data: [link](https://justpaste.it/9hcf0)

Answer (score 0):

Just an update:

This [thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1851518) helped me find a solution that worked for me.

I added `options snd-hda-intel model=mono-speakers` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and rebooted.

Works fine now. Although I still have to jump through a few hoops (suspend pc, unplug & re-plug headphones).